# Should the "subject alternative name" property of an X509 certificate be set to critical?

Tags: ssl-certificate

I'm writing a tool to generate self-signed X509 certificates and X509 certificate requests and I'm wondering how the "critical" property of the SubjectAlternativeName (OID 2.5.29.17) should be handeled. The [documentation](http://www.alvestrand.no/objectid/2.5.29.17.html) isn't too clear for me.

Should I:

- Make it critical
- Make it non-critical
- Let the user decide
- Ask the question on stackoverflow instead ?

Thanks